# Can I use the new Lion OS X license on two machines, or do I have to buy one for each?

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, upgrade, license

I have 2 macbooks (the unibody and the one before that). Do I need to buy two licenses or can I just use one license for both machines?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Like everything else you purchase in the Mac App Store, you can install Lion on all of your Macs after buying it once. There is no activation process or DRM.

Here's the relevant excerpt from Lion's license agreement (emphasis mine):

> If you obtained a license for the Apple Software from the Mac App
>   Store, then subject to the terms and conditions of this License and as
>   permitted by the Mac App Store Usage Rules set forth in the App Store
>   Terms and Conditions (http://www.apple.com/legal/itunes/ww/) ("Usage
>   Rules"), you are granted a limited, non-transferable, non-exclusive
>   license:
>
> (i) to download, install, use and run for personal, non-commercial
>   use, one (1) copy of the Apple Software directly **on each Apple-branded
>   computer** running Mac OS X Snow Leopard or Mac OS X Snow Leopard Server
>   ("Mac Computer") **that you own or control**;

Comment: So the new family license is just buying one copy from the App Store and installing it on everyone in the family's computers?

Comment: @Brant, the excerpt you quote mentions "personal, non-commercial use". What about commercial use (ie, installing both on my home and work Macs)?

Comment: @Daniel: Hmm, good question, I don't know. You should ask another question about commercial uses. :)

Comment: @DanielSerodio when I read : http://images.apple.com/legal/sla/docs/macosx107.pdf , I understand that for commercial use, we must have one license per machine.      What about Mac developer program, cans we use it for legally downloading stable Lion version, for all company machines?

Answer (score 2):

Technically you can use the Lion installer app from the app store to all your mac. Don't forget to move the installer from Applications folder before install Lion. it will deleted if you won't move the installer after the installation process.

Another good alternative is to create bootable DVD installer for Lion. You can use it to install Lion for all your mac. Follow this step to create it

> http://www.macworld.com/article/161069/2011/07/make_a_bootable_lion_installer.html

Anyway i have tried both from installer app and bootable DVD installer to install Lion for several mac. It works well.

Comment: I routinely offer caution about a DVD burnt in that way for 10.7 (Build 11A511), see for example recently discussed [home-produced bootable media for Lion: known risks and unknowns around 10.7 (Build 11A511)](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38/conversation/home-produced-bootable-media-for-lion-known-risks-and-unknowns-around-10-7-buil).

Answer (score 2):

You have to have your employer buy a license.

Your personal license can be used to install Lion on every Mac you own or control for personal, non-comercial, use. So it can't be used to install Lion on your computer at work. Your employer can buy a license and use it to install Lion on each of the Macs it owns or controls, as the following statement says:

> If you obtained a license for the Apple Software from the Mac App Store [...] you are granted a limited, non-transferable, non-exclusive license [...] (if you are a commercial enterprise or educational institution) to download, install, use and run one copy of the Apple Software for use [...] by a single individual on each of the Mac Computers that you own or control

Taken from: http://images.apple.com/legal/sla/docs/macosx107.pdf