# Can I update both of my mac with the single purchase of OSX

Tags: macos

I would like to purchase OSX 10.8(Mountain Lion) using my apple account.

The question is am having two mac computers with snow leopard, Can I update both of my mac with the single purchase?

any help?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. With one purchase you can uptate all your macs that <s>are linked to your iTunes account</s> you own.

[How to upgrade to 10.8 on Apple.com](https://www.apple.com/en/osx/how-to-upgrade/).

Comment: They don't need to be under your iTunes account—you only need to "own or control" them.  See this answer, which is applicable to ML: http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/17885/21050

Answer (score 0):

If your macs are using the same iTunes account (i.e. same appstore) you can do multiple updates with one purchase.